# Limiting range in OnEdit timestamp script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I would like to be able to limit the range of cells being assessed by this script to the first column. Apply the timestamp to the last column and only have the script run on a specific sheet "Short Sale/REO Pricing".

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();

  // check the column
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { 
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This needs testing but something like this:

change

```
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) {
```

to:

```
  if( r.getColumn() == 2 && s.getName() == "Short Sale/REO Pricing" ) {
```

test the above, then change:

```
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
```

to:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, s.getLastColumn()).setValue(time);
```

The google-apps-script is "javascript".